# How to transform UIView's bounds space like GL space?

Tags: uiview, uikit, touch, transform, coordinate-systems

I'm handling `UITouch` event sourced from `UIView`. The problem is the coordinates are specified in UIView's bounds, left-top corner originated point space. But my GL viewport is defined in left-bottom originated (Y-flipped), pixel space.

I can convert all touch coordinates manually, however, if I could set custom transform on coordinate system of UIView, this will be solved automatically. Is this possible? What I want to do ultimately is receiving `UITouch` with my custom coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Use an affine transform:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0);

view.transform = transform;
```